# ¿Cómo hacer una pirámide de números?

Tags: python, while

Quiero hacer una pirámide poniendo con `n=5` para que me salga algo así:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Pero con mi código me sale así xD:

```
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
```

Estas son mis líneas: (al parecer me falta quitar los números de la derecha que en si tambien seria un triángulo)

```
n = int(input("N filas: "))
cf = 0
a=0
while n>9 or n<1:
    n = int(input("N filas: "))

while cf<n:
    cf+=1
    a=1

    while a<=n:
        
        print(a, end="")
        a+=1
    print("")
```

No quisiera que me den la respuesta en menos lineas de codigo porque aun no estoy acostumbrado y quiero entenderlo :c quiero que se mantenga la esencia de cómo lo estoy haciendo (bucles anidados). Gracias :)

Comment: que lenguaje estas usando? agrega todas las etiquetas que puedas para que puedan ayudarte mejor

Comment: el lenguaje python, así se llama creo :v (estoy usando pycharm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creé este script, espero pueda ayudarte:

```
n = int(input("Número: "))
ind = 0
numbers = []

while ind < n:
    ind += 1
    numbers.append(ind)
    print(*numbers)
```

Lo que hará es que irá agregando a una lista los números desde 1 hasta "n", siendo "n" el límite que se le ingrese por consola.

La variable {ind} es el número que se agregará a la lista en el ciclo, empieza como cero y al entrar en el ciclo crecerá de uno en uno mientras se agrega a la lista para al final imprimirla en pantalla y reiniciar el ciclo. El resultado final, si el usuario ingresa un cinco será:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Si quieres que no haya ningún espacio entre los números puedes agregar un `sep = ""` en el `print(*numbers)`, dejándolo como `print(*numbers, sep = "")`

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con recorrer cada nivel e imprimir lo que necesites en cada nivel con un loop:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def print_level(level):
    for number in range(1, level + 1):
        print(number, end=" ")
    print()

def print_levels(levels):
    for level in range(1, levels + 1):
        print_level(level)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LEVELS = 5

    print_levels(LEVELS)
```